# how to marge two columns under the same column header in mysql

Tags: mysql, merge, multiple-columns, using

How to produce the table below using SQL Query, where CHEMISTRY,CA1,CA2, ExAM,TOT,came from ChemTable, PHYSICS,CA1,CA2,ExAM,TOT,came from PhyTable and ENGLISH,CA1,CA2,ExAM,TOT,came from EngTable. Thanks

```
 __________________________________________________________________________
|       CHEMISTRY        |         PHYSICS        |     ENGLISH            |   
|________________________|________________________|________________________|
| CA1 | CA2 | EXAM | TOT | CA1 | CA2 | EXAM | TOT | CA1 | CA2 | EXAM | TOT |
|_____|_____|______|_____|_____|_____|______|_____|_____|_____|______|_____|
```

Comment: I don't think what you're suggestion can be done using SQL. You're showing two column headers, where an SQL query would only retrieve 1.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a UNION of the 3 selects:

```
SELECT "CHEMISTRY" as class,CA1,CA2, ExAM,TOT from Chemtable
UNION    
SELECT "PHYSICS" as class,CA1,CA2, ExAM,TOT from PhyTable    
UNION
SELECT "ENGLISH" as class,CA1,CA2, ExAM,TOT from EngTable
```

But really you would want to normalize your table structure.

Comment: No the table is not appearing the way it should be. I mean the columns CA1, CA2, EXAM and TOT where under the CHEMISTRY column header and the same is applied to all. thanks for your prompt respond

Comment: You don't put columns in columns as SQL output. You would handle that in the View of the data.